# Using CSS Grid to position child divs within parent divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a grid container with several other divs inside of it. [image]
The heading, paragraph, button and logos are all within their own divs. I've used Flexbox to space the logos out across the entire width of the container. However, I want to position the div with all of the logos in it at the very bottom of the grid container. How can I do this? Here is the markup:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.logos-container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: end;
}

.logos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Making remote work</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        Get your team in sync, no matter your location. Streamline processes, create team rituals, and watch productivity soar.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="logos-container">
      <div class="logos">
        <img src="images/client-databiz.svg" alt="databiz logo">
        <img src="images/client-audiophile.svg" alt="audiophile logo">
        <img src="images/client-meet.svg" alt="meet logo">
        <img src="images/client-maker.svg" alt="maker logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="images/image-hero-desktop.png" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little modification, I was able to get this: https://jsfiddle.net/c1jx5p6u/1/

It involved moving the logo-container to the root of the grid-container, and setting grid-areas.

This is because with the logos-container div inside the box div, it was positioning in the grid areas as one item. Moving it out of the box div, it can be moved separately into the grid areas created on the grid-container.

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "head side"
    "main side"
    "footer footer";
}
.logos-container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: end;
  grid-area: footer;
}
.logos{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: end;
}
.box{
  grid-area: head;
}
.boxside{
  grid-area: side;
}

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Making remote work</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Get your team in sync, no matter your location. Streamline processes, create team rituals, and watch productivity soar.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logos-container">
    <div class="logos">
      <img src="images/client-databiz.svg" alt="databiz logo">
      <img src="images/client-audiophile.svg" alt="audiophile logo">
      <img src="images/client-meet.svg" alt="meet logo">
      <img src="images/client-maker.svg" alt="maker logo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxside">
    <img src="images/image-hero-desktop.png" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

[image: Could you pls check your IMG div.]

You can arrange images as per your design.

```
.logos-container {
  display:flex;
  align-items: end;
}

.logos img{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```
<div class="box">
      <img src="images/image-hero-desktop.png" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="logos-container">
      <div class="logos">
        <img src="images/client-databiz.svg" alt="databiz logo">
        <img src="images/client-audiophile.svg" alt="audiophile logo">
        <img src="images/client-meet.svg" alt="meet logo">
        <img src="images/client-maker.svg" alt="maker logo">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).